# MySQL logging max_questions resource

Tags: mysql-5.6, users, limits, mariadb-10.3

How would I know in MySQL if the user has exceeded his max_queries per hour?
I know that I can see this error on the client side, but I just want to know that before client is reporting to me, somewhere on the server side, would be nice to have it in error_log at least.

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific status variable for queries per user in MariaDB. You can only monitor `Queries` and `Questions` status variables on your monitoring system.